# Integral of Kolmogorov-Smirnov metrics?

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, information-theory

I want to to calculate the area of the differences between the (red) null and (blue) empirical distributions of x, like in

[image: this]

, the arrow is the KS metric, but is there a name for the area between the curves? And how does it relate with Information Entropy (Shannon)?

If the distributions are not exactly identical, the area will be >0. Just to be clear, I am not interested by Area(red)-Area(blue), but by the integral |red-blue|. Not the difference of integrals, but the integral of absolute differences. The way I see it relating to entropy and information content is when you consider uniform distribution for the null.

Many thanks in advance,

Seb

Comment: I don't know what that area is called, but it certainly is not a good metric for how different the null and empirical distribution are. The area could be 0 while both distributions are still very different. Note also that the difference in area is simply the difference in the expected value of both distributions.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst That is an accurate and (seemingly) complete reply.  (Well, I suppose you could also point out the obvious: namely, that the difference in expectations has nothing at all to do with entropy.)  If you get the time, please consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, there might be a misunderstanding then. If the distributions are not exactly identical, the area will be >0.
Just to be clear, I am not interested by Area(red)-Area(blue), but by the integral |red-blue|. Not the difference of integrals, but the integral of absolute differences.
The way I see it relating to entropy and information content is when you consider uniform distribution for the null.

Comment: You should make this clarifications as an edit to the post! Comments are easily overlooked, and can be deleted.

Comment: The *signed* area will equal the difference in expected values.  The integral of the absolute difference is, by definition, the $L^1$ distance between the two distribution functions.